# Django - How to tertermine content_type in if statement?

Tags: django, content-type

I want to find out what content_type I'm about in my function but I'm Unable to reach the "got me" print statement no matter how I design my if statement. I also tried to use pprint to get the naming of the content_type but with no effect till now.

```
def mark_refunded(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(status=2)
    transactions = queryset.all()
    for transaction in queryset.all():
        print(transaction)
        transaction.sender.acc_usd_balance += float(transaction.amount)
        transaction.sender.save()
        transaction.receiver.acc_usd_balance -= float(transaction.amount)
        transaction.receiver.save()
        print(transaction.content_type)
        if transaction.content_type == "App | Sell Type A":
            print("got me")
```

It seems that I'm unable to compare the output of  print(transaction.content_type) with the if statement, why that?
I would expect that the output is the same value that I ask for at the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `content_type` is a foreign key, you'd need to compare `if str(...) == ...`.

However, the more important issue here is that multiple concurrent requests will eventually absolutely surely corrupt those account balances since you're not managing them in an atomic way.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, I would probably never have figured it out myself, thanks!